# How to install Typo3 extension: jfmulticontent

Tags: typo3

Beeing new to Typo3, I've just installed jfmulticontent, but obvisouly, there's more to it than simply importing and installing. The documentation that comes with it on the other hand seems to be nice for people, who already know what they are doing. Does anybody know, where I can find some beginner-friendly installation-instructions and general documentation about that plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure you import the static files of the extension.

> After installing the extension, you have to add the static “Multi
>   content (jfmulticontent)” to your template

[image]

I don't know your site structure. Try click on template, then click on your site root. Choose **Info/Modify** from toolbar and then click on **Edit the whole template record, Includes**.

Extension manual: http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/jfmulticontent/2.7.3/view/toc/0/

**Try to be more specific regarding your problem. This way we can help you much better.**